# Drupal 8 JSON API : Convert relative url to absolute url

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I am using json api to fetch my sites content. The body field in the article contains some images which when fetched using json api returns image path in relative format (eg : `sites/default/files/08-2016/abcd.png`). But I want this images path in absolute format (eg : `http://www.mywebsite.com/sites/default/files/s/08-2016/abcd.png`).

Comment: I have exactly the same issue; unfortunately Drupal community does not want to fix it: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2911490

Comment: Try using a Normalizer to alter the URL output.